# Convert [String: AnyObject] to [String: Any]

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

I have a Swift variable of type [String: AnyObject] however the function i'm trying to invoke requires a  [String: Any] (This would be a Dictionary

```
fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes
```

Any thoughts on what I should do in a situation like this?

Thanks!

Comment: What have your tried?  How/Where is the 'I have a Swing variable' variable defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me in a playground. Not sure it's the most efficient way, especially for a large dictionary, but it might work for your case.

```
var anyObjectDict = [String: AnyObject]()

anyObjectDict.updateValue("test", forKey: "key1") 
anyObjectDict.updateValue(1.0, forKey: "key2")

var anyDict = [String: Any]()

for key in anyObjectDict.keys {
    anyDict.updateValue(anyObjectDict[key], forKey: key)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out to help me! Just an update that in my case I had to do anyDict.updateValue(reportData[key]!.description, forKey: key)  instead but it's all good thanks so much :)