# Handling Swift Dicts: fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes

Tags: swift, casting, fatal-error

I have a function in Swift that needs to be able to handle multiple types.  Specifically, it needs to be able to parse both Dicts and Strings.

The problem I have is the Dicts could be several types, depending on their origin.  So I could be provided with `[String:Any]` or `[String:String]` (coming from Swift) or `[String:AnyObject]` (coming from objc).  The top level parsing function takes `Any`, which it then tests for specific types and attempts to parse them.

At first I just tried testing for `if let dict = object as? [String:Any]`, but if I passed in another type `[String:AnyObject]` or `[String:String]` it failed.  So I tried testing each type:

```
func parseLink(object: Any) {

    if let dict = object as? [String:Any] {
      return self.parseDict(dict)
    } else if let dict = object as? [String:AnyObject] {
      return self.parseDict(dict)
    } else if let dict = object as? [String:String] {
      return self.parseDict(dict)
    } else if let string = object as? String {
      return parseURL(string)
    }
}

func parseDict(dict: [String:Any]) { ..... }
```

So I've created some Unit Tests to test the behavior:

```
  func testDictTypes() {
    let testDict: [String:Any] = [ "orgId" : "123456789" ]

    let link = OrgContextLinkParser().parseLink(testDict)
    XCTAssertNotNil(link)

    let testDict1: [String:AnyObject] = [ "orgId" : "123456789" ]

    let link2 = OrgContextLinkParser().parseLink(testDict1)
    XCTAssertNotNil(link2)

    let testDict3: [String:String] = [ "orgId" : "123456789" ]

    let link3 = OrgContextLinkParser().parseLink(testDict3)
    XCTAssertNotNil(link3)
  }
```

This all compiles fine, but I get a fatal runtime error if a `[String:AnyObject]` is passed in.  This is troubling since Swift's type system is supposed to prevent these kind of errors and I get no warning or errors thrown when I compile.

I also really don't want to duplicate the exact same logic multiple times just to handle different dict types.  I.E., handling `[String:Any]`, `[String:AnyObject]` and `[String:String]` have virtually the exact same logic.

The only possible solution I've seen is to actually duplicate the dictionary, which seems rather expensive ([Convert [String: AnyObject] to [String: Any]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005474/convert-string-anyobject-to-string-any)).  For performance reasons, it seems better to just copy paste the code and change the function signatures... but really!?  That's seems excessive.

The best solution seems to be to parse a Dict as `[String:AnyObject]` and copy the value *only* if it's `[String:Any]`:

```
if let dict = object as? [String:Any] {
  var objDict: [String:AnyObject] = [:]
  for (key, value) in dict {
    if let obj = value as? AnyObject {
      objDict[key] = obj
    }
  }
  return self.parseDict(objDict)
```

I don't particularly like this, but so far it's be best I've been able to come up with.

Does anyone have any idea how to handle this properly?  I'm especially concerned that I can cast `Any` as `[String:AnyObject]`, pass it to a function that takes `[String:Any]` and I get no compiler errors, even though it crashes at runtime.

Comment: Don't use `Any`, use at least `AnyObject` even as function parameter: `func parseLink(object: AnyObject) { ... `

Comment: hmmm.... that would simplify things.  But I would have to define it in the protocol (something I didn't mention for sake of brevity), and that means I could not parse Swift structs... something I might actually need to do.  I'll give this some thought though.